# Safari: Ignoring a lot of CSS

Tags: html, css, safari

We've began testing our site in different browser and all of them work fine, except Safari (Mac & windows).

Edit: Removed url!

On our page. The image doesn't float right, and the preface text is not bold. If I add

```
style="float: right;"
```

and

```
style="font-weight: bold;"
```

it works in Safari.

The CSS for these elements are:

```
.articleimage
{
    float: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.articlepreface
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.articlebody
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and this works fine in all other browsers we've tried.

Any ideas why Safari behaves like this? The page validates as XHTML Strict 1.1

Comment: seems this also applies to Chrome. When using inspect, the styles do not show up in the list

Comment: You are better off putting IE6 hacks in a separate stylesheet and using conditional comments in the (X)HTML source to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IE6 hack you've used in tine.css is causing the problems. Removing the hack fixes both the float and bold issues.

Comment: yes, you're right. We moved it to the bottom and everything works.

Comment: @Tommy for the record what was the faulty IE6 hack?